# How to override property in extension in Swift

Tags: swift, unit-testing, mocking

```
extension UIScreen {
  static var width: CGFloat { return UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width }
  static var height: CGFloat { return UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height }
}
```

I want to mock this two var in Unit test, set width as 414, height: 736, Any idea?

Comment: is it your problem that they don't appear (accessed) in testing cases?

Comment: you can use the @objc attribute for a method or property:

Comment: @AhmadF they can access in UnitTest, but these value depends on the device which I test(iPhone6 and iPhone6 Plus are different), I want to set them as a static value.